# PHP Code not displaying Like same HTML code

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a website, where I uploaded an `index.html` which is completely made of HTML code (no PHP).

I copied this code over to an PHP file `index.php`, furthermore I separated the header into a separate php file. When I cleaned up the new `index.php`, I just used an `include()` to include the header, like so:

```
<? include("TopNote.php"); ?>
```

So the difference between `index.html` and `index.php` is that the HTML code is directly in the `index.html` and in the PHP file, it is included from a seperate PHP file.

Now the `index.php` file give a strange button, where the `index.html` displays it all the way I want it to display.

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/style.css">
  <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .ui-menu { position: absolute; width: 100px; }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#menu" ).buttonset();
      $( "#regdialog" ).dialog();
      $( "#buttonregister" ).click(function() {
        $( "#regdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#aaaaaa">
  <img src="example.lorg" alt="" style="padding-left:20px" />
  <div align="right" style="padding-right:20px">
    <div>
      <button id="StaffLogin">Staff Login</button>

      <button id="select">Select an action</button>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      <li id="buttonregister"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
  <form style="margin-top: 1em;">  
    <div id="menu" align="center">
      <input type="radio" id="buttonhome" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="buttonhome">Home</label>
      <input type="radio" id="buttonforums" name="radio"><label for="buttonforums"><a href="http://example.org">Forums</a></label>
      <input type="radio" id="buttonapply" name="radio"><label for="buttonapply"><a class='fb_iframe' href="http://example.org">Apply</a></label>
      <input type="radio" id="buttonabout" name="radio"><label for="buttonabout">About Us</label>
      <input type="radio" id="select" name="radio">
    </div>
  </form>



  <br />
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Alert:</strong> The Site Is No Where Near Completed, Please go to our <a href="http://example.org/">Forums</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- POP UP -->
  <div id="regdialog" title="Register">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
          <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            Registrations are not working!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5>Username:</h5>
      <input type="text" name="reg_name">
      <h5>Password:</h5>
      <input type="password" name="reg_pass">
      <h5>Confirm Password:</h5>
      <input type="password" name="reg_pass_conf">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/style.css">
  <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#aaaaaa">
  <? include("TopNote.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`topnote.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/style.css">
  <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .ui-menu { position: absolute; width: 100px; }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#menu" ).buttonset();
      $( "#regdialog" ).dialog();
      $( "#buttonregister" ).click(function() {
        $( "#regdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#aaaaaa">
  <img src="example.lorg" alt="" style="padding-left:20px" />
  <div align="right" style="padding-right:20px">
    <div>
      <button id="StaffLogin">Staff Login</button>

      <button id="select">Select an action</button>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      <li id="buttonregister"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
  <form style="margin-top: 1em;">  
    <div id="menu" align="center">
      <input type="radio" id="buttonhome" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="buttonhome">Home</label>
      <input type="radio" id="buttonforums" name="radio"><label for="buttonforums"><a href="http://example.org">Forums</a></label>
      <input type="radio" id="buttonapply" name="radio"><label for="buttonapply"><a class='fb_iframe' href="http://example.org">Apply</a></label>
      <input type="radio" id="buttonabout" name="radio"><label for="buttonabout">About Us</label>
      <input type="radio" id="select" name="radio">
    </div>
  </form>



  <br />
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Alert:</strong> The Site Is No Where Near Completed, Please go to our <a href="http://example.org/">Forums</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- POP UP -->
  <div id="regdialog" title="Register">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
          <p>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            Registrations are not working!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5>Username:</h5>
      <input type="text" name="reg_name">
      <h5>Password:</h5>
      <input type="password" name="reg_pass">
      <h5>Confirm Password:</h5>
      <input type="password" name="reg_pass_conf">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the difference, and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`topnote.php` should not have doctype, html and head since you already added in the index.php

Avoid the Short Tag which will be XML complaint, use like below

```
<?php include 'file.php'?>
```

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Thanks, removed not only the tags, but also everything that was inside the <head> tags, that made it work.

Answer (score 3):

You can not have a `<html>` tag inside a `<body>` tag. Your `topnote.php` does not need to have a doctype, head and all that stuff. Because `index.php` defines already html, doctype, head, title and so on.

So your `topnote.php` should only contain this elements:

```
<img src="http://destiny-craft.com/img/Logo_Resized.png" alt="" style="padding-left:20px" />
<div align="right" style="padding-right:20px">
  <div>
    <button id="StaffLogin">Staff Login</button>

    <button id="select">Select an action</button>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
    <li id="buttonregister"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>  
<form style="margin-top: 1em;">  
   <div id="menu" align="center">
            <input type="radio" id="buttonhome" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="buttonhome">Home</label>
            <input type="radio" id="buttonforums" name="radio"><label for="buttonforums"><a href="http://forums.destiny-craft.com">Forums</a></label>
            <input type="radio" id="buttonapply" name="radio"><label for="buttonapply"><a class='fb_iframe' href="http://destiny-craft.coffeecup.com/forms/ApplyForm/">Apply</a></label>
        <input type="radio" id="buttonabout" name="radio"><label for="buttonabout">About Us</label>
        <input type="radio" id="select" name="radio">
    </div>
</form>



<br />
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            <strong>Alert:</strong> The Site Is No Where Near Completed, Please go to our <a href="http://forums.destiny-craft.com/">Forums</a></p>
    </div>
</div>






<!-- POP UP -->
<div id="regdialog" title="Register">
<form action="#" method="post">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            Registrations are not working!</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <h5>Username:</h5>
    <input type="text" name="reg_name">
    <h5>Password:</h5>
    <input type="password" name="reg_pass">
    <h5>Confirm Password:</h5>
    <input type="password" name="reg_pass_conf">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

And you can move your `<script>` tags which are in the `<head>` tag of your `topnote.php` to the end of `topnote.php`. It's valid and better practice to put them right before the closing `</body>` tag. That ensures that all DOM elements are loaded at this point.